# How can I find items using Bitter Squirrel summon?

Tags: god-of-war-2018

There is one loading screen tip saying that it's possible to get some special rewards from using Ratatoskr (Bitter Squirrel summon) in some locations. Looks like it's possible to get something other than health and rage crystals.

What are these locations and what items can I get? Is there any in-game indication on these locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, special locations for Ratatoskr exist, but you can only find extra hacksilver there, no fancy items.

Locations are marked with special white circle symbol on the ground:

[image: white circle]

This [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/GodofWar/comments/8fm50g/possible_next_in_game_secret_pls_help_guys/) has 14 such locations listed with [this map](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/180503/v3d5ae2g.jpg) as well.